# Select subset of Data Frame rows based on a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df1` and list `x`:

```
In [22] : import pandas as pd
In [23]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C': range(5), "B":range(10,20,2), "A":list('abcde')})
In [24]: df1
Out[24]:
   A   B  C
0  a  10  0
1  b  12  1
2  c  14  2
3  d  16  3
4  e  18  4

In [25]: x = ["b","c","g","h","j"]
```

What I want to do is to select rows in data frame based on the list. 
Returning

```
   A   B  C
1  b  12  1
2  c  14  2
```

What's the way to do it?
I tried this but failed.

```
df1.join(pd.DataFrame(x),how="inner")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to return a boolean index for you to index into your df:

```
In [152]:

df1[df1['A'].isin(x)]
Out[152]:
   A   B  C
1  b  12  1
2  c  14  2
```

This is what `isin` is returning:

```
In [153]:

df1['A'].isin(x)
Out[153]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use df[df["column"].isin(values)]