# How do I subset a pandas data frame based on a list of string values?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dF that's over 100k rows long, and a few columns wide — nothing crazy. I'm trying to subset the rows based on a list of some 4000 strings, but am struggling to figure out how to do so. Is there a way to subset using something like.

The dF looks something like this

```
dog_name    count
===================
Jenny        2
Fido         4
Joey         7
Yeller       2
```

and the list of strings is contained the variable `dog_name_list=['Fido', 'Yeller']`

I've tried something along the lines of 
`df[df['dog_name'].isin(dog_name_list)`, but am getting a fun error: `unhashable type: 'list'`

I've checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210757/select-subset-of-data-frame-rows-based-on-a-list-in-pandas), the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)   and [this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/02/16/pythonpandas-column-value-in-list-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous/) rundown for subsetting data frames by seeing whether a value is present in a list, but that's got me right about nowhere, and I'm a little confused by what I'm missing. Would really appreciate someone's advice!

Comment: Check if there are any lists in your `dog_name` column: `any((isinstance(v, list) for v in df.dog_name))`

Comment: Your command is correct, probably a data issue as Alexander points out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you have a list in your dog name column.

This works fine:

```
>>> df[df['dog_name'].isin({'Fido', 'Yeller'})]
  dog_name  count
1     Fido      4
3   Yeller      2
```

But if you one of those dogs happens to have a list for a name instead of a string, you will get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
df.ix[4] = (['a'], 2)
>>> df
  dog_name  count
0    Jenny      2
1     Fido      4
2     Joey      7
3   Yeller      2
4      [a]      2

>>> df[df['dog_name'].isin({'Fido', 'Yeller'})]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-1b68dd948f39> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['dog_name'].isin({'Fido', 'Yeller'})]
...
pandas/lib.pyx in pandas.lib.ismember (pandas/lib.c:5014)()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

To find those bad dogs:

```
>>> df[[isinstance(dog, list) for dog in df.dog_name]]
  dog_name  count
4      [a]      2
```

To find all the data types in the column:

```
>>> set((type(dog) for dog in df.dog_name))
{list, str}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. @Alexander, oddly enough `any((isinstance(v, list) for v in df.dog_name))` returns `false`

Comment: Try to ensure the data is all strings: `all((isinstance(dog, str) for dog in df.dog_name))`