# In Pandas, how to filter a Series based on the type of the values?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `Series` like

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['foo', 'bar', 42])
```

I would like to obtain a 'sub-series' `pd.Series(['foo', 'bar'])` in which all values are strings. I've tried Boolean indexing like so:

```
s[isinstance(s, str)]
```

but this gives a

> KeyError: False

In my search for suitable methods so far I came across [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.select.html), but this imposes a criterion on the labels, not the values. How can I filter based on (the type of) the values in this case?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `apply` or list comprehension:

```
s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Same as, thanks `Jon Clements♦`:

```
s[s.apply(isinstance, args=(str,))]
```

---

```
s[[isinstance(x, str) for x in s]]
```

All return:

```
0    foo
1    bar
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

This is not recommended, thanks [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999146/in-pandas-how-to-filter-a-series-based-on-the-type-of-the-values/46999157?noredirect=1#comment80945145_46999157):

```
s[s.apply(type) == str]
```

Comment: I'd avoid advocating the use of `type(...) == ...` if I were you, it's not pythonic. `isinstance` is the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, the `s[[isinstance(x, str) for x in s]]` is also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351629/how-do-i-subset-a-pandas-data-frame-based-on-a-list-of-string-values.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it depends if you need strict str checking or not... In Python 2.x, isinstance against `basestring` would make sense for instance... Depending whether you want anything that inherits from `str` to be considered a string or not.

Comment: @jezrael I'd suggest...`s.apply(isinstance, args=(str,))` for your first example and avoid the lambda

Comment: Basically, `isinstance` covers inheritence hierarchy as well. For example, `isinstance(True, int)` is true, but `type(True) == int` is False. In python2 this is especially important. Because unicodes and strs are treated differently. You'd handle it with `isinstance(x, basestring)`, but not with `type` as easily.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, see above, I was typing exactly that.

Comment: So we are forced to using a iterative method through `apply`, which is slower and discouraged. If I want to drop rows *in-place* based on this, I'd have to run this apply, pass it to the df to get the index series, and then pass that to `df.drop()` to drop the rows in-place.

Answer (score 5):

A little trick with `pd.to_numeric`:

```
s[pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').isnull()]

0    foo
1    bar
dtype: object
```

If an item is numeric, it is successfully coerced (not `NaN`) and so is dropped from the final result.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `pd.to_numeric` as pointed above.

Alternatively, you can use `str.isalpha`

```
In [109]: s[s.str.isalpha().notnull()]
Out[109]:
0    foo
1    bar
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why non-strs give NaN instead of False, that's inconsistent.