# Deleting rows of pandas dataframe based on instance type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Basically I am trying to delete rows of a pandas dataframe where values in a certain column are not instances of datetime. I have tried:

```
df = df[df[‘date’] == isinstance(datetime)]
```

I know isinstance takes two arguments (I am missing the value to be checked) but I’m not sure what to put there.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance) says, `.isinstance` takes `object` as the first argument and `classinfo` as the second argument.

The correct way is as follows:

```
import datetime 
df.loc[df['date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.datetime))]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Doesn’t this change the values of the column to true/false only? I want to keep the original values that are dates but get rid of the ones that aren’t.

Comment: @big11mac, You are absolutely right. That True/False is your mask. You can always query from that mask. See the edit.

Comment: Ok I understand. So this would be the same as: df = df[df[‘date’].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,datetime))] ?

Comment: @big11mac, precisely.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, you should convert your series to `datetime` and then mask for non-null values:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

df = df[df['date'].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

With small change to the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999157/5916727), you can try following:

```
df = df[df['date'].apply(isinstance, args=(datetime,))]
```