# When sorting a dataframe, why do I get "TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()" when there are no NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe, `data`, containing about a million rows, of addresses and their latitudes and longitudes (i.e., the columns are `Add`, `Lat` and `Lon`). I'm trying to sort it according to the values in column `Lat`:

```
data = data.sort_values(['Lat'])
```

But it gives the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-c45d0eeb9ddb> in <module>()
----> 1 data = data.sort_values(['Lat'])

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   4425 
   4426             indexer = nargsort(k, kind=kind, ascending=ascending,
-> 4427                                na_position=na_position)
   4428 
   4429         new_data = self._data.take(indexer,

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py in nargsort(items, kind, ascending, na_position)
    253         non_nans = non_nans[::-1]
    254         non_nan_idx = non_nan_idx[::-1]
--> 255     indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
    256     if not ascending:
    257         indexer = indexer[::-1]

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

So I thought there must be some missing values in `Lat`. Since I could not manually check 1 million rows, I did a binary search to try and find the row responsible for the error (or at least a small subset of rows containing the row responsible for the error), by trying to sort every subset. I narrowed it down to  38 rows:

```
df = data.iloc[262125:262163]
df = df.sort_values(['Lat'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-c45d0eeb9ddb> in <module>()
----> 1 data = data.sort_values(['Lat'])

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   4425 
   4426             indexer = nargsort(k, kind=kind, ascending=ascending,
-> 4427                                na_position=na_position)
   4428 
   4429         new_data = self._data.take(indexer,

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py in nargsort(items, kind, ascending, na_position)
    253         non_nans = non_nans[::-1]
    254         non_nan_idx = non_nan_idx[::-1]
--> 255     indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
    256     if not ascending:
    257         indexer = indexer[::-1]

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

beyond this point, I could not continue the binary search further as both the subsets, `262125:262144` and `262145:262163` do not give the error above. Strange!

**I manually checked these 38 rows for any missing `Lat` values, but there were none.**

Furthermore, I also extracted this 38-row subset of the dataframe as a CSV file, imported it as a new dataframe, and this time the sorting works!

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df.sort_values(['Lat'])
# This works
```

Yet, when I select the subset from the original dataframe and try to sort it, it gives the error. What is going on? Any help or insight is appreciated.

***P.S.***: Another interesting observation I made is, when I take the 38 rows as a subset of the original dataframe, I can check if there is any missing value in it:

```
df = data.iloc[262125:262163]
df[df['Lat']=='']
# Returns a blank dataframe
```

But when I try to do the same after reading the 38 rows from the CSV file saved earlier, I encounter an error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df[df['Lat']=='']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-eb2036e18be2> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['Lat']=='']

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1281 
   1282             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1283                 res = na_op(values, other)
   1284             if is_scalar(res):
   1285                 raise TypeError('Could not compare {typ} type with Series'

c:\users\hm38\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1167                     result = method(y)
   1168                 if result is NotImplemented:
-> 1169                     raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
   1170             else:
   1171                 result = op(x, y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is with mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':['a',2,3]})
print (data)
  Lat
0   a
1   2
2   3

#data = data.sort_values(['Lat'])
```

So possible solution is convert all non numeric to `NaN`s by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`

```
data['Lat'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Lat'], errors='coerce')

data = data.sort_values(['Lat'])
print (data)
   Lat
0  2.0
1  3.0
2  NaN
```

EDIT:

You can check all non numeric values:

```
df = data[pd.to_numeric(data['Lat'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
print (df)
  Lat
3   a
```

Comment: But I don't want to convert the values into `NaN`s, since the values are all legitimate longitudes and latitudes. How about just converting them from `str` to `int` instead?

Comment: If the type of the column is numeric then it must be `float` because pandas does not allow a mix of `NaN` (which is a `float`) and `int`s.

Comment: @Kristada673 - Another idea - Can you check last edit and find if some values are strings? Can you add output to question?

Comment: @jezrael What I found, interestingly, is that if the dataframe contains an actual string like in `data = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':['a',2,3]})`, then your edit does indeed list out the non-numeric entries. However, if the string is not an "actual string", but rather a number stored as a string, like `data = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':['1',2,3]})`, then your edit does not list out anything.

Comment: @Kristada673 - Yes, I agree, then is necessary only `data['Lat'] = data['Lat'].astype(int)`

Comment: I see. So, when I saved the 38 row dataframe as a CSV, and then read it as a new dataframe, did the type of `Lat` automatically become `int`? If yes, how?

Comment: @Kristada673 - It depends of data. If no `NaN`s and only integer, pandas in `read_csv` automatically convert column to `integer`s.

Comment: @Kristada673 - If want remove `NaN` and no parseable to numeric (original column `Lat` are integers), then is possible use `data[pd.to_numeric(data['Lat'], errors='coerce').notnull()]` and then `data['Lat'] = data['Lat'].astype(int) `

Comment: @jezrael With the `astype(int)` solution, I get the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '14.5928565'`.

Comment: @Kristada673 - Original values are `float`s? then use `data['Lat'] = data['Lat'].astype(float) `

Comment: @jezrael Still get error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Lat'`

Comment: @Kristada673 - So need `data[pd.to_numeric(data['Lat'], errors='coerce').notnull()]` and then `data['Lat'] = data['Lat'].astype(float)`

Comment: yeah, tried that too - same error. And also same error with `data['Lat'].apply(float)`.

Comment: @Kristada673 - Are you sure? Do you use `.notnull()` ?

Comment: @Kristada673 - Are data confidental? If use `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['Lat'])` and then `df.to_csv('Lat.csv')` is possible share it? By gdocs, or dropbox or send it to my email in my profile?

Comment: @jezrael It is confidential indeed, as they are address of people's homes. But even if I did share the CSV file with you, it won't replicate this error as I stated in the question. So, it won't help, right?

Comment: So if share only column `Lat` it is problem? `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['Lat'])` ?

Comment: Ok, if I share only the `Lat` column, will that be ok? If yes, how do I get your email address please? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177173/discussion-between-kristada673-and-jezrael).

Comment: data = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':['1',2,3]})  How do I detect data like '1'? I faced same error in sort_values.

Comment: @kakoli use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999157/2901002)