# Get non-float values from specific column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get in a new dataframe the rows of an original dataframe where there is a non-real (i.e. string) value in a specific column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test = {'a':[1,2,3],
        'b':[4,5,'x'],
        'c':['f','g','h']}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df_test)
```

I want to get the third row where the value in 'b' column is not numeric (it is 'x').

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your problem from your English, can you clarify more about what you want and what your problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771133/finding-non-numeric-rows-in-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999146/in-pandas-how-to-filter-a-series-based-on-the-type-of-the-values

Comment: The topic "Finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?" does not solve my question. I need to get the non numeric values from specific columns instead from the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The complication is that Pandas forces column elements to have the same type (object for mixed str and int) so simple selection is not possible. Hence I think it is necessary to iterate over the column of interest to select the row(s) and then extract that/those.

```
mask = []
for j in df_test['b']:
    if isinstance(j, str):
        mask.append(True)
    else:
        mask.append(False)
        
print(df_test[mask])
```

which produces

```
   a  b  c
2  3  x  h
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform some type of list comprehension or element-wise apply and build a boolean mask for this type of problem. You can use any of the following approaches (you should see similar performance for all).

### isinstance .apply

```py
mask = df_test['b'].apply(isinstance, args=(str, ))

print(df_test.loc[mask])
   a  b  c
2  3  x  h
```

### isinstance list comprehension

```py
mask = [isinstance(v, str) for v in df_test['b']]

print(df_test.loc[mask])
   a  b  c
2  3  x  h
```

### coerce to numeric and find nans

```py
mask = pd.to_numeric(df_test['b'], errors='coerce').isna()

print(df_test.loc[mask])
   a  b  c
2  3  x  h
```